# Using splot in Gnuplot; How to do 'w lines' for one column and 'lc palette' based on another column

Tags: gnuplot

I have an orbit simulator that formats my data file as

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhF3A.png)

The first column is the timestep, 2nd column is the body and then x,y and z for the last three.

What I need my plot to do is

splot 'Filename.txt' u 3:4:5:2 w lines...

but I can't figure out the formatting for using the body number for lines and then column 1 for the color to show the the orbit evolve over time. I'm sure it's incredibly simple.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "using the body number for lines".  The command as shown will use columns 3,4,5 for the x,y,z of successive points along a line, and ignore column 2. What did you want it to do with the value in column 2? As to using column 1 for the color, that would be `splot file u 3:4:5:1 with lines lc palette`.

Comment: @JoMi, is this solved or still of interest? Please give any kind of response and post data as text not as image.